# Dynamic UIApplicationShortcutItems reseting when iOS Language Preferences are changed

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplicationshortcutitem

My app is using dynamic [UIApplicationShortcutItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationshortcutitem), allowing the user to choose their own custom shortcuts. When the OS language preference is changed, this list is being reset, removing all of the shortcuts and requiring the user to recreate their list. Any ideas on what might be causing this and/or how to prevent it? The app only supports English.

I am adding the shortcuts with:

```swift
UIApplication.sharedshortcutItems = userChosenFeatures.map { 
    UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: $0.id, localizedTitle: $0.name, localizedSubtitle: nil, icon: UIApplicationShortcutIcon(templateImageName: $0.iconName)) 
}
```